# Android to take memory footprint

Tags: android, eclipse, memory-management, heap-memory

As the title indicates, what are the best ways to take memory footprint and what need to be provided in memory footprint for an android app.

I already have googled and found many blogs for detecting memory leak via eclipse MAT tool. Kindly correct me is this the right way.

Comment: Yep, Eclipse MAT is the right way to go. I guess you already know from different articles how to collect heap dump files, convert them to the format acceptable by MAT, and conduct some analysis. Just tell me if you need any more specific info regarding your question.

Comment: @Android777 yes, I already have did that. It shows the number of objects, shallow heap, retained heap of each class. Just want to know what I should mention in footprint. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for not answering for some time. Still I'm not sure what to answer, it looks like you have something more specific in your mind. If you simply need to know how much memory is allocated in a heap, you can use the Memory Monitor tool in Android Studio / Intellij IDEA. That's a quick method, MAT is more appropriate for digging into details.